# How to query all posts by tag_id in Postgres ManyToMany Relationship in spring JPA repository?

Tags: spring, postgresql, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

How to query all posts by tag_id in Postgres ManyToMany relationship in Spring JPA repository?

These are the tables:

| post | post_tag | tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | id_post | id |
| .. | id_tag | .. |

If I query the PostgreSQL directly via pg_admin Query tool the following sql is working:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE ID IN (
select post_id from post_tag tag WHERE (tag_id = '12'))
```

I like to have this query in my JPA Repository, but the following isn't working.

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE ID IN (select post_id from 
    post_tag tag WHERE (tag_id = id))",nativeQuery = true,)
    fun findPostsByTagId(id: String): Optional<List<Post>>
```

How to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `WHERE (tag_id = :id)`

Comment: That does not work for me :(

Comment: what does not work? are you seeing any error? are you getting incorrect result? what is expected and what is actual output?

Comment: It says : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = character varying

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE ID IN (select post_id from 
    post_tag tag WHERE (tag_id = :id))",nativeQuery = true,)
    fun findPostsByTagId(id: Long): Optional<List<Post>>
```

1. add ":" in front of "id" like sidgate says
2. changing String to Long for the passed parameter